# Multisite setup with drush

Tags: drush, multi-sites

Is it possible to set up multisite with drush including folder creation and database setup?

Answer (score 1):

For the first site:

`drush qd --sites-subdir=<directory name>`

For each successive site:

`cd DRUPAL_ROOT_CREATED_ABOVE
drush qd --use-existing --sites-subdir=<directory name>`

These will create sqlite databases.  Add --db-url with valid database credentials to use a pre-existing database.  Also add --db-su and --db-su-pw to make Drush create the database for you.

Haven't tried some of the steps in this workflow in a while; report any problems back in the Drush issue queue.  Also, you might want to use drush master instead of 6.x.  There's a issue in the queue that hasn't landed yet that makes [drush qd better](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/1177).

**UPDATE:** Drush quick-drupal does not appear to be well suited for multisite usage.  For subsiquent sites, call `drush site-install` with `--sites-subdir` and `--db-url` options.  See `drush help si` for more information on options that may be useful here.

For example

```
drush si --sites-subdir=<folder> --db-url=mysql://db_user:str0n6passw0rd@localhost/db_name
```